# #temporary table Microsoft SQL seems to get lost

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a little exercise where I need to access data from a view and print it out in a report. I have created a #temporary table to store the data in and the to retrieve it and display it in the report by using a while loop.

Problem is the temporary table seems to go 'missing'.

```
--Creating my report
USE PetShopDataBase
CREATE PROCEDURE spPetShopReport 
@customerID INT

SELECT *
INTO #temporary
FROM vwPetshop
WHERE customerID = @customerID
GO

ALTER TABLE #temporary
ADD Printed SMALLINT
GO
```

Then from this point the object is regarded as invalid

```
UPDATE #temporary
SET Printed = 0
GO
```

the error message I get when I run the code is

```
Msg 4902, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
Cannot find the object "#temporary" because it does not exist or you do not have 
permissions.
```

Why is that?

Kind regdards

Comment: where/how did you create temp table? can you show TSQL code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do not use GO inside of a stored proc. Go ends the batch and thus the stored proc.

BTW way all of this code can be compressed into one statement

```
SELECT * INTO #temporary 
FROM vwPetshop 
WHERE customerID = @customerID   

ALTER TABLE #temporary 
ADD Printed SMALLINT 

UPDATE #temporary 
SET Printed = 0
```

try this instead:

```
SELECT *, CAST(0 AS SMALLINT) AS Printed
  INTO #temporary 
FROM vwPetshop 
WHERE customerID = @customerID
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use global temporary table in this case (just two ## instead of one #)..

```
SELECT *
INTO ##temporary
FROM vwPetshop
WHERE customerID = @customerID
```

Local temporary tables are not visible outside procedure in which it was created..

Comment: bad idea, these temp tables can be used by other users and you could create issues from that.